# How do you access this property from typescript class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, this

I have googled about this and nothing seems to work for me. I saw where I can use `var self = this;` I tried that but when I print the value of `self` it says undefined. I am not sure if the typescript would work differently. I know it transpiles to Javascript under the hood. I am using Typescript 2.6 version.

Here's my AppComponent code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 5';


  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $("#file").change(this.loadFile)
  }
  loadFile(e)
  { 
    var self = $(this)
    console.log(" Name -> " + this.name)
    console.log(" This variable " + self.name)
    var file = new FileReader();
  }

}
```

Why is this.name not defined? I understand that loadFile is a call back function, but I want to be able to access my class variable inside this function. 
Once you upload any file the `loadFile(e)` function will be triggered.

Link to the project is 
[Click Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu4rje?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Why the JQuery `$()` around `this`? In fact: why use JQuery at all in an Angular app?

Comment: You don't need to use JQuery with angular.

Comment: Ya, you guys are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery triggers the `change` handler function (in your case `loadFile`) with a different `this`.

You have two options:

- Use [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    $("#file").change((e) => this.loadFile(e))
  }
  ```
- Use [**`.bind()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    $("#file").change(this.loadFile.bind(this))
  }
  ```

---

Although, I suggest you ditch jQuery altogether and use Angular for the event listening, e.g.

```
<input type="file" (change)="loadFile($event)" />
```

Comment: The first solution with arrow function worked for me. Thank you very much.